# Few Large SELECTS or Many Small SELECTS (Both Serial) for HTTPHandler?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection, httphandler, large-data

I'm trying to export large excel files from database (client request).  I currently use two selects to get data from two tables and store them in two sqldatasets.  I have a delay before the file starts uploading since each table gives up to 100k rows.

I've turned off the outputbuffer in the httphandler, and I export each row from the first table as its' own vb.net html table (with dependent rows from the second dataset).  Once the upload begins, it's very fast, but client still wants to get rid of that delay.

I was thinking I could break up the two large selects into many small selects to use as I build the html tables, opening and closing each connection.

Can sql server handle it?

What are the downsides?

I've looked everywhere and can find nothing.  Many thanks in advance!

**Limitations**

The second table is dependent upon the first table, so I can either hit it once for everything and loop or many time for each row of the first table...right?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my previous answer. I was confused.

Two possibilities I see here:

1. Your query is slow.
2. You are converting query result to an in-memory collection (people commonly do `.ToList()` where as they totally don't need to).

In both cases we would need to see you code. One thing I can tell you is that splitting your query on subset queries is likely to slow you down.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the difference between sqldataset and datareader?  How does the datareader read if it doesn't hold the same info as the sqldataset?  Thank-you very much!

Comment: A data reader (`SqlDataReader` in your case) will load records into memory one by one, where as data set is a cache of everything from your query. The idea is to get rid of unnecessary buffering. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Actually I just realized you probably talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx which (if used correctly) will provide the same type of streaming access, so my answer is incorrect. Please show some code so I can see what the issue is.

Comment: Aren't both held in memory?  I think that's what's causing the delay.  It's loading upwards of 100MB into .net from sql server.  I think the best approach for speed is to break it up into individual queries, but I don't know if sql server can handle 200k serial connections hitting rapid fire.  Can't find docs either.  Thank-you!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy "Aren't both held in memory?" Not necessarily. Like I said, you need to show your code for me to make better judgement.

Comment: Yep, I was dumping into a dictionary (stupidly) and hadn't tested it to see if that was fully the culprit although setting the sqldatasets to nothing after i populated my dictionaries did speed it up a lot. I'll give +1 once I can confirm that huge sqldatasets aren't the problem.  Thanks again!